# Create a circular barplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would be interested in using a circular barplot visualisation for my project, and have no idea whatsoever how to produce it in Python. Please see an example of what I mean for "circular barplot" below. Data would come in form of a pandas series - dummy example below to vaguely reflect the plot:

```
A 33
B 62
C 56
D 70
```

Any idea?

[image: here, using R]

Comment: How do you provide your data? A dictionary? A list? Please add a sample input.

Comment: Good point, updating question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is just an horizontal bar plot in polar projection. Matplotlib defaults will make it look a bit different.

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.barh(0, math.radians(150))
ax.barh(1, math.radians(300))
ax.barh(2, math.radians(270))
ax.barh(3, math.radians(320))
```

[image]

But it can be tuned:

- Use `set_theta_zero_location()` to make the bars start at North.
- Use `set_theta_direction()` to make the bars go clockwise.
- Use `set_rlabel_position()` to move the radial labels.
- Use `set_thetagrids()` and `set_rgrids()` to set the ticks and labels.

The result is very similar:

```
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
ax.set_thetagrids([0, 96, 192, 288], labels=[0, 20, 40, 60])
ax.set_rgrids([0, 1, 2, 3], labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

[image]

There must be a way to move the radial labels to the left of the bars but I could not find it.

**PS** A more concise and maybe faster way:

```
ax.barh([0, 1, 2, 3], np.radians([150, 300, 270, 320]),
        color=plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also make use of the dismissed donut plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from math import log10

labels = list("ABCDEFG")
data = [21, 57, 88, 14, 76, 91, 26]
#number of data points
n = len(data)
#find max value for full ring
k = 10 ** int(log10(max(data)))
m = k * (1 + max(data) // k)

#radius of donut chart
r = 1.5
#calculate width of each ring
w = r / n 

#create colors along a chosen colormap
colors = [cm.terrain(i / n) for i in range(n)]

#create figure, axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis("equal")

#create rings of donut chart
for i in range(n):
    #hide labels in segments with textprops: alpha = 0 - transparent, alpha = 1 - visible
    innerring, _ = ax.pie([m - data[i], data[i]], radius = r - i * w, startangle = 90, labels = ["", labels[i]], labeldistance = 1 - 1 / (1.5 * (n - i)), textprops = {"alpha": 0}, colors = ["white", colors[i]])
    plt.setp(innerring, width = w, edgecolor = "white")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Love this plot.  Thanks for taking the time to share it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with matplotlib. The trick is to draw barplots in polar coordinates. Have a look at this example, taken from matplotlib documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/polar_bar.html

Other kinds of "circular bar plots" can be made based on these examples:
https://python-graph-gallery.com/donut-plot/

More info on https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/donut_chart.html

However, I don't know a *direct* way to get what you're looking for using matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks yes I was aware of that example and used that template in the past. However, in that example the bar "move" along the radial direction, while I would like them to "grow" along the polar direction

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately the donut plot in matplotlib does not work either as it's basically a pie chart with a white hole in the middle.

Comment: The trick could be to create successive pie charts, by successively decreasing the `radius` parameter of `pyplot.pie`. It's not very convenient, I agree ;-)