# Labels on circular barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, bar-chart

Thanks to answers on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729748/create-a-circular-barplot-in-python) I was able to produce my first circular barplot in python.

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('S')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
ax.set_yticklabels(['','','','first','second','third','fourth','fifth'])
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.grid(False)
ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
ax.barh([0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8], np.radians([0,0,0,0,30,50, 100, 130, 180]),color=plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])
```

Output plot is shown below.

I now would like to format the labels so to be in line with the bars, and hopefully display the value of the lenght of the bar aside the uppper end of the bar. Tried various examples borrowed from regular (not circular) barplots in matplotlib, but none seems to apply.

[image]

Comment: While you specify which labels to show you do not specify where to show those labels. Use `.set_xticks()` to specify the positions.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this solved the problem indeed: ax.set_yticks([4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5])