# How to make a particular visualization in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

So this may not be the right forum to ask this question but

1. I don't know what this type of visualization is called (hence I'm not able to google it). The dynamic version where the colors run up the semi-circle as the graphic loads.
2. Any tips on how to create this in Python? Although I guess once I know what its called, I can google how to make it in Python. :)
3. What is the right place to ask such a question? Some sub-reddit?

Thx

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a ["Radial Bar Chart"](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/radial_bar_chart.html), the Data Visualization catalogue link has recommendations.

If you want Python specifically, there is a previous thread on plotting in `matplotlib` with polar coordinates ([Circular Barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729748/create-a-circular-barplot-in-python)), but I don't think this will handle your preference to "[dynamically update colors] as the graphic loads."

[This page from AMCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/radial-bar-chart/) has an in-browser version that seems like it would fit. Dump your data into `json` and it should work.